# Google Sheets two way calculation/updating/iterative calculation

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I have a google sheet dataset. Great! Using filter() to run a few reports off of it. No problem.

The issue is, the end-users want to be able to put comments into the reports that have been run off, and have the main dataset update based on these comments. Additionally, as things change, the data in the reports move around. They'd like the comments they make to move around with them.

So what I initially did was created a "Comment database", which checked every report and the main dataset for comments, and pulled them in. Works like a charm.

I also included a OR(Not(Now()="Dummy") clause to the comment database aggregation to force recalculation every time a change was made.

I then enabled iterative calculations (Tried at 1, 2, and 3 iterations), and had everything be an index-match back to the comments, with the idea being that if someone entered a new comment, it would update the dataset, which would then update the main report once they dragged the formula back over.

In Excel, this would work perfectly - the iterative calculation would "store" the comment value, and it would continue to cycle through.

However, in Google sheets, this isn't working.

I've asked if the obvious solution of "Just update the main dataset whenever you want to change something" would work. For reasons unknown, the answer is no.

How can I get what I want? I'm open to using google scripts if necessary, although I'm not too familiar with the language.

As an example:

Dataset:
ID: 123
Comment: None

Report:
ID: 123
Comment: "Hello World"

Becomes:

Dataset:
ID:123
Comment:"Hello World"

Report:
ID:123
Comment:"Hello World"

The comment has moved from the report to the dataset

Then once we add ID 456:

Dataset:
ID: 123
Comment: "Hello World"
ID: 456
Comment: None

Report:
ID: 456
Comment: None
ID: 123
Comment: "Hello World"

The comment has moved down with the ID it's associated with

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out I had a bad conditional statement, and fixing it fixed the problem.

This type of system will work as a two-way street for information, it's just silly convoluted.

Comment: This isn't really a full answer. Where is the fixed conditional statement? It may help others to see the fixed version.